# Web Scraping Data Destination

Tags: vba, excel, web-scraping

I am very new to using VBA in Excel. I have a list of hundreds of links that I want to scrape the data from (the links do not have nicely formatted tables, I have to scrape the raw data for what I need). I have a macro built that is working nicely, but the destination is not quite what I'm hoping for.

I want excel to read each url, and then dump the data in the next column over. BUT I want each set of data to appear directly below the previous. So I want all of the data from all of the URLs in the same column. Currently, my macro is putting the data from each URL into its own column.

Example: 
My URLs are listed in each row separately in column A. The macro reads A1 and dumps the in Data B1. Then, it shifts that column to the right a bit (so it is now C1), and dumps the data from A2 into (the new) B2.

What I want it to do is read A1, and put the data in B1. Then, read A2 and put the data in B30 (if B29 was the last used row for the data from A1).

Hopefully this makes sense.

Here is the macro I currently have working:

```
Sub WebScraping()
Dim Erw, Frw, Lrw
Frw = 1
Lrw = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For Erw = Frw To Lrw
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "URL;" & Range("A" & Erw).Value, Destination:=Range("B" & Erw))
        .Name = ""
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .WebSelectionType = xlEntirePage
        .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
        .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
        .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
        .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
        .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
        .WebDisableRedirections = False
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
Next Erw
End Sub
```

And here are some examples of the URLs I am scraping:
http://www.washington.edu/students/timeschd/AUT2018/arctic.html
http://www.washington.edu/students/timeschd/AUT2018/hnrs.html

Thanks for any suggestions!

[So the yellow URL is the first in the list, and the red URL is the second in the list. The yellow column to the right is where it is placing the data from the first URL, and the red column to the right is where it is placing the data from the second URL. But I want to it to first place the data from the first URL in Column B, then place the data from the second URL directly below that.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R1zH3.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write to the next available row in B (Or add some padding rows in between as well)

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub WebScraping()
    Dim Erw As Long, Frw As Long, Lrw As Long, LrwB As Long
    Frw = 1
    Lrw = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & ActiveSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For Erw = Frw To Lrw

        LrwB = ActiveSheet.Range("B" & ActiveSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

        With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
                                         "URL;" & ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Erw).Value, Destination:=ActiveSheet.Range("B" & LrwB))
            .Name = vbNullString
            .FieldNames = True
            .RowNumbers = False
            .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
            .PreserveFormatting = True
            .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
            .BackgroundQuery = True
            .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
            .SavePassword = False
            .SaveData = True
            .AdjustColumnWidth = True
            .RefreshPeriod = 0
            .WebSelectionType = xlEntirePage
            .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
            .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
            .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
            .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
            .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
            .WebDisableRedirections = False
            .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
        End With

    Next Erw

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions!! I tried that and it is still putting the different sets of data in different columns though..... I added a picture to the original post to show what it is currently doing. Hopefully that clarifies my question?

Comment: Works perfectly - thank you!!! Do you by chance know if there is a way to tell it to skip any links that don't have data for it to pull from? For example, if I use this link in my list:

https://www.washington.edu/students/timeschd/SUM2018/arctic.html

the macro has an error that says:

"Run-time Error 1004, Unable to open "URL") 

Is there a way to make it just skip trying to read that one? Or any resources I could check out to try to find a way? Thanks so much for your help, I am very new at this!!

Comment: You could try a simple On Error Resume Next ....code that fails......On Error GoTo 0.  It is a bit like putting a blanket over the problem to pretend it is not there. So maybe LrwB = ... On Error Resume Next  With  <.........other code......>. End With.....On Error GoTo 0 Next Erw